# Download google docs image as local file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a bit of VBA code that works well in downloading a jpg file from a web address and then saves it as a local file. I can also do the same for a google sheet and save it as a csv file. When I attempt to download an image file from google docs the file seems to download but it is un-viewable. Can anyone help me with this.

This is the VBA code I'm using.

```
Sub DownloadFileFromURL()

Dim myURL As String, sFilename As String
myURL = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1f6pKXGikYrVVQydFQ0TXZqSXc"
sFilename = "C:\Dump\file.jpg"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False ', "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile sFilename, 2  ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
   oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The URL you're using is not the URL to the actual JPEG. The actual JPEG is located at https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/PQAfz_ZVyub9WiSdM190cZhctHZj8177M-A_8kzdv_ocER0hVW-L832vCwOk4l_oX-zGeCJMWdlWo14=w1280-h891. You need to use that link to download it.

Comment: I set the image for sharing with anyone who has the URL the file downloads but it is always unviewable. It displays fine in a web browser https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z6VzOR9zC85V0huYN1XGgMCgq-f2DvRn

Comment: Yes, that's incorrect, like I just told you. Don't do that, use the correct URL, like the one I provided

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I guess you need a login at Google. Using that link returns a _403 Forbidden_ error.